Checking if a word in string contains a palindrome
I want to find if a string contains a palindrome word. An example would be hellosannasmith contains a palindrome word and should return sannas, however givemefood should return none. I first tried it through 2 for loops then I started to think why not a while loop but before I begin going the while loop route I want to see if it can be done in 2 for loops first.
I managed to get san into the new palindrome string variable but I'm not sure what else I am missing or overlooking here. Any help would be greatly appreciated.


function SearchingChallenge(str) {
  var palindromeStr = "";

  for (var i = 0; i < str.length / 2; i++) {
    for (var j = str.length - 1; str.length / 2 < j; j--) {
      if (str[i + 1] == str[j - 1] && str[i] == str[j]) {
        palindromeStr += str[i];
      }
    }
  }

  if (palindromeStr == "") {
    return "none";
  }

  return palindromeStr;
}

console.log(SearchingChallenge('hellosannasmith'));
console.log(SearchingChallenge('givemefood'));




What steps have you taken to debug this?

@mykaf I'm using pen and paper to visualize the result and I came to the conclusion the if condition can be fixed to something "better" but don't know just yet how to approach it

This is not the same question as the duplicate. There are more efficient ways than checking if every single substring is a palindrome.

@DonDavid12 What is the definition of "word" here? Any string of length at least 2?

That wasn't specified in the task of the problem but yes let's go with that for the moment @Unmitigated

Do you need to find the longest palindromic substring or just any?

Assuming that it has one palindrome in the substring @Unmitigated

@DonDavid12 There is another palindrome in 'hellosannasmith' though: 'll'.

@Unmitigated When 2-letter words are considered. Also: nn and anna btw.

@KooiInc Yes, that's true. I ended up just implementing a method for finding the longest palindromic substring.

First, by comparing str[i] = str[j] you can come to "palindrome" without having a palindrome. imaging "abcdefcba": for i=1,2,3, j=n-1,n-2,n-3 str[i] === str[j]. however they not connected, because in between you have other stuff.
Secondly, in the same check you checking both str[i]===str[j] and str[i+1]===str[j-1] means the last char answering the criteria will not be entering the result (apart when they meet at the center, like your first example)
So what you have to do is to check for every given interval if a substring in the given interval is a palindrome.
Check the below example:


function isPalindrome(str) {
  return str === str.split('').reverse().join('');
}

function SearchingChallenge(str) {

  if(str.length <= 1) return 'none';
  
  for(let i=0;i<str.length-3;i++) {
    for(let j=str.length-1; j>i+2; j--) {
        
        const substr = str.substring(i, j);
        if(isPalindrome(substr)) return substr;
    }
  }

  return 'none';
}

console.log(SearchingChallenge('hellosannasmith'));
console.log(SearchingChallenge('givemefood'));
console.log(SearchingChallenge('abcdef'));
console.log(SearchingChallenge('someawesomeemosik'));



Lastly, remember two things:

There can be more then one palindrome in the string. so you have to decide weather you return the first instance, or you return array of all found palindromes. (in the example above i returning first found)
You should define minimum chars of the accepted palindrome. Probably 1char you dont wanna consider palindrome. how about 2? "aa" is a palindrome? and 3? in your second example, givemefood, eme is a palindrome then. in above example min palindrome length set ton three. but it need to be defined


This helps but I'm trying to understand why in the second loop we decided to have j>i+2 and why chose +2 in this case?

Can you fix your repeated misspellings of "palindrome"?

@DonDavid12 its related to second point I pointed at the end. The question is what is the minimum length of a palindrome you will consider a palindrome. in my example I set it to 3 letters. For this I need each substring I check to have  at least 3 letters, so j-i >=3 or j-i>2

Something to consider is that your outer loop is only looking at the first half of the string and the inner loop is only looking at the second half of the string, meaning you are not checking for all possible substrings. Your approach is only considering whether one exists at the center of the string.
Another note is that your condition if(str[i + 1] == str[j - 1] && str[i] == str[j]) is only checking pairs of characters at a specified position. So you are doing a partial character check, not an entire substring. So you end up building your string when two pairs match, which does not guarantee it's a palindrome.
Try making it more readable and robust by adjusting your loops:
  for (let i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
    for (let j = i + 1; j <= str.length; j++) {

Then you can build your substring using those indices


You can define a Set() including all the words and then use dynamic programming to find the longest palindrome.

You can also add some conditions to return a palindrome, once found in the set. (It's unclear from the question).




const words = new Set(["hello", "sannas", "smith", "give", "me", "food"]);

function SearchingChallenge(str) {
  const n = str.length;
  if (n === 0) return "none";

  let res = "";
  const dp = Array.from({ length: n }, () => Array(n).fill(false));

  for (let len = 1; len <= n; len++) {
    for (let i = 0; i <= n - len; i++) {
      const j = i + len - 1;
      if (len === 1) {
        dp[i][j] = true;
      } else if (len === 2) {
        dp[i][j] = str[i] === str[j];
      } else {
        dp[i][j] = str[i] === str[j] && dp[i + 1][j - 1];
      }
      if (dp[i][j] && len > res.length) {
        res = str.slice(i, j + 1);
      }
    }
  }

  return words.has(res) ? res : "none";
}

console.log(SearchingChallenge("hellosannasmith"));
console.log(SearchingChallenge("givemefood"));




Note:

This function has to be modified, to fulfill the requirements of the challenge.


You can simply use Manacher's algorithm to find the longest palindromic substring in linear time (O(N)) in the number of characters in the string.


function findLongestPalindromeSubstring(str) {
  const pOdd = Array(str.length).fill(0), pEven = Array(str.length).fill(0);
  let lOdd = 0, rOdd = 0, lEven = 0, rEven = 0, maxLen = 0, start = 0;
  for (let i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
    if (rOdd > i) pOdd[i] = Math.min(rOdd - i, pOdd[lOdd + rOdd - i]);
    while (i - pOdd[i] >= 0 && i + pOdd[i] < str.length &&
      str[i - pOdd[i]] === str[i + pOdd[i]]) ++pOdd[i];
    if (i + pOdd[i] > rOdd) lOdd = i - pOdd[i], rOdd = i + pOdd[i];
    if (2 * pOdd[i] - 1 > maxLen) {
      maxLen = 2 * pOdd[i] - 1;
      start = i - pOdd[i] + 1;
    }
    if (rEven > i) pEven[i] = Math.min(rEven - i, pEven[lEven + rEven - i + 1]);
    while (i - 1 - pEven[i] >= 0 && i + pEven[i] < str.length
      && str[i - 1 - pEven[i]] === str[i + pEven[i]]) ++pEven[i];
    if (i + pEven[i] > rEven) lEven = i - 1 - pEven[i], rEven = i + pEven[i];
    if (2 * pEven[i] > maxLen) {
      maxLen = 2 * pEven[i];
      start = i - pEven[i];
    }
  }
  return maxLen > 1 ? str.slice(start, start + maxLen) : 'none';
}
console.log(findLongestPalindromeSubstring('hellosannasmith'));
console.log(findLongestPalindromeSubstring('givemefood'));
console.log(findLongestPalindromeSubstring('abc'));





simply use 9 local bindings, some nested loops, 14 conditionals, 13 mutations, and another loop for good measure!


to improve this answer, I think you should link the algorithm and include a basic explanation of how it works. I'm a fan of the comma operator but I'm wondering why it's applied inconsistently? Ie, why do some if consequents get , whereas others get { ...; ...; }?

@Mulan I appreciate the feedback. Simple may not have been the correct word, in hindsight; I mainly meant this is the standard method for solving most palindrome problems efficiently. As for not using the comma operator everywhere, I was trying to avoid horizontal excessive horizontal scrolling in the code snippet. Additionally, I wrote this code from memory, not following a specific paper. I could link the Wikipedia page but it uses a slightly modified version of the algorithm.

I think the problem you're describing is this
Longest palindromic substring

You make one for loop to iterate over the characters of the string
inside point 1's loop, you will write a loop to expand left and right. this will help you find palindrome which may be off odd length
inside point 1's loop, you will write another loop to expand from left and right + 1, to accommodate for even number length palindrome.

I don't have for javascript, but here's one for Java
public String longestPalindrome(String s) {
        int n = s.length();

        int maxLen = 0;
        int maxL = 0;
        int maxR = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < n ; i++) {
            int l = i, r = i;

            while (l >= 0 && r < n && s.charAt(l) == s.charAt(r)) {
                int len = r-l+1;
                if (len > maxLen) {
                    maxLen = len;
                    maxL = l;
                    maxR = r;
                }
                l--;
                r++;
            }

            l = i; r = i + 1;

            while (l >= 0 && r < n && s.charAt(l) == s.charAt(r)) {
                int len = r-l+1;
                if (len > maxLen) {
                    maxLen = len;
                    maxL = l;
                    maxR = r;
                }
                l--;
                r++;
            }
        }

        return s.substring(maxL, maxR+1);

    }


A string can contain multiple palindromes. Here's a function that can return all of them (an array), or just confirm the existence of a palindrome within a given string (true/false). Before checking the input string is converted to a string containing [a-zA-Z] only (so all spaces, interpunction etc. are removed).
Play with (a more worked out version of) this code @Stackblitz


const strings = JSON.parse(document.querySelector(`#strings`)
  .content.textContent);
const result = document.querySelector(`#result`);

// just check for palindrome existence
strings.forEach(string => {
  const found = getPalindromesInString({str2Check: string, single: true});
  result.innerHTML += `<b>Are there palindromes in</b>\n<i>${
    JSON.stringify(string)}</i>?<span>${
      found.error 
      ? ` => ${found.error}` : found ? ` => SURE` : ` => NOPE`}
    </span>\n`;
});

result.innerHTML += `<hr>`;

// retrieve all palindromes
strings.forEach(string => {
  const found = getPalindromesInString({str2Check: string});
  result.innerHTML += [
    `<b>All palindromes in</b>\n<i>${JSON.stringify(string)}</i>`,
    `${JSON.stringify(found, null, 2)}`]
    .join(`\n`) + `\n\n`;
});

function getPalindromesInString({ 
    str2Check, 
    caseSensitive = false, 
    single = false, 
    isPalindrome = stringIsPalindromeFactory() } = {}) {

  if ( str2Check?.constructor !== String || str2Check?.length <= 1 ) {
    return {error: `invalid input`};
  }
  
  str2Check = str2Check.replace(/[^a-z]/gi, ``);
  const result = [];
  
  
  for (let i = 0; i < str2Check.length; i += 1) {
    for (let j = str2Check.length; j > i + 2; j -= 1) {
        const substr = str2Check.substring(i, j);
        const palindromeFound = substr.length > 1
          && isPalindrome(substr, caseSensitive);
        palindromeFound && result.push(substr);
    }
  }
  
  return single ? result.length > 0 : result;
}

// Recursive palindrome determination
function stringIsPalindromeFactory() {
  return function maybePalindrome(string, cs = false) {
    const lc = cs ? string : string?.toLowerCase();
    return lc[0] !== lc.at(-1) ? false : tail(lc.slice(1, -1));
  };

  function tail(str) {
    return !str.length 
      ? true : str[0] !== str.slice(-1) 
        ? false : tail(str.slice(1, -1));
  };
}
b {color: green; }

i {
  display: inline-block; 
  margin-left: 1rem;
  color: blue; 
}

span {color: red; }
<template id="strings">[
  "I don't think we'll find palindromes",
  "It's Anna I am talking about, or quod non so m eawe so meem sos and finally tattarrattat",
  "A man, a plan, a canal: Panama",
  "T. Eliot, top bard, notes putrid tang emanating, is sad; I'd assign it a name: gnat dirt upset on drab pot toilet.",
  {"invalid": "input"} ]
</template>

<pre id="result"></pre>



